# Is there an adjective for "full of people"

Tags: word-request

> He was walking in a ___ street.

I can only think of a way to say this:

> He was walking in a street brimming with people.

However, I am looking for an adjective and I can't think of any.

Comment: Your own examples show ways to do this using participles as adjectives. Some others: "crowded," "jammed," "packed," etc. Is there some reason you want to avoid participles?.

Comment: You might use "congested", but that could be more than just people (cars, buses).

Comment: Your starting point should be your bilingual dictionary.  What is the word in your own language? What does your bilingual dictionary offer as a translation.  Why are you unsure of that translation?

Comment: _Brimming_ means _full to the brim_, so it's not the most appropriate way to describe a crowded street.